# Rails: validate fields on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, simple-form

Here is the thing. Let's say I have a user model, order model and an address model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :address, :foreign_key => :address_id, :class_name => "Address"
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :address, :foreign_key => :address_id, :class_name => "Address"
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :email, :address
end
```

Now on the user model I would like to validate just the email field of the address model.

But on the Order model I would like to validate just the address field of the address model.

I have tried this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :address, :foreign_key => :address_id, :class_name => "Address"
     validate :address_fields

     def address_fields
        self.address.errors.add 'email' unless self.address.email.present?
     end
end
```

It does work in the console but Simple Form does not see the error and does not show it.

Any idea to properly do it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're close, but there are some subtleties depending on what you're trying to do.

Generally, Rails is set up for model-centric validation - that is, a model is either valid or it's not. Rails is expecting your validations to be present on the model you're validating, and provides the [`validates_associated` validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated) to help with that. Here's an example where I've put some rules on the `Address`, and told the `User` and `Order` models to validate them when saved.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  validates_associated :address
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  validates_associated :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :orders
  attr_accessible :email, :address

  # This isn't a good regex for validating email addresses, it's just an example
  validates :email, format: { with: /^[A-z0-9]+@[A-z0-9.]+.[A-z]$/ }
  validates :address, presence: true
end
```

You can also have [conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation), using the `:if` and `:unless` options on the validation. For instance, if you wanted to require a phone number on an `Address` only if it's a US `Address`, you could use this:

```
validates :phone_number, presence: true, if: :us_address?
def us_address?
  country == "United States"
end
```

If your `Address` can have many users (for instance, more than one person might order to a company address) and can have many orders (because customers can order more than once), it's hard to write a conditional validation on the `Address` model that obeys the rules you asked for. There's a couple of alternatives that spring to mind:

- Store the email on the `User` model instead. You can't email buildings, so it kind of makes more sense there. If you'd like to snapshot the user's email address so you can reproduce invoices, then maybe include a `confirmation_sent_to_email` field on your `Order`.
- Have two separate models, an `OrderAddress` and a `UserAddress`. They can have different validation rules, and it'll become clearer in your application which type you're dealing with. You could still have an `Address` model that solely holds the address details, and associate that with `OrderAddress` and `UserAddress` models as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your two suggestions seems a bit messy but gave me an idea. How about to have two subclasses for the address model, OrderAddress and UserAddress. The only difference would be the validation. Would that work?

Comment: You could do it that way - Rails would like you to do that using [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance) - but I'd still be inclined towards option 1. It would be harder to add DB-level constraints by using STI, and it's harder to eyeball the data and determine if it's OK or not.

Answer (score 1):

An simple answer.

Add errors to user instead of user.address.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     def address_fields
        self.errors.add 'email' unless self.address.email.present?
     end
end
```

Then you can see errors on your Simple Form of user.

Or you can update your users form like this, to handle user.errors and user.address.errors as well:

```
  <% if @user.errors.any? || @user.address.errors.any?%>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count + @user.address.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
      <ul>
      <% @user.address.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will show the error on the user field and not next to the email field... no?

Comment: It depends on how you handle the errors on your form. On your users form, usually handle errors like `<% if @user.errors.any? %>` . If you want show more errors you can update to `<% if @user.errors.any? || user.address.errors.any? %>`. See my updates.